# indicator-bluetooth-service high CPU and memory usage

Tags: bluetooth

The indicator-bluetooth-service is using up 50-75% of my CPU and memory and making my fan go crazy. Killing it alleviates the issue temporarily, as not long after, it starts up again hogging my important resources.

What I really want is to permanently disable the indicator-bluetooth-service or if possible delete it. I tried deleting it with synaptic, but that strangely deletes the system settings (which I do need). Any suggestions?

Many thanks.

p.s. I'm using Unity 14.04 on a Toshiba Portege Z30a notebook.

Answer (score 1):

Installing Xubuntu-desktop seems to have solved the issue. Bit disappointed ... I was starting to like Unity!

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. the system uses all the memory (4 Gb) and all the swap space (4 Gb) and it crashes, the system stops working. It takes a couple of hours. According to monitor system, the indicator-bluetooth-service was using the memory. In ma case I fixed by removing the recognized and stored bluetooth devices from the bluetooth manager. It stopped and now is working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its a bug with Unity-Panel. See [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1199877).

Unless any other fix, please install any other Desktop Environment such as **[GNOME](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CEkQFjAL&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.howtogeek.com%2F189912%2Fhow-to-install-the-gnome-classic-desktop-in-ubuntu-14.04%2F&ei=wHpkVZO7J8iLuwTI54CIBQ&usg=AFQjCNEw2LEMu27L5ZHtOcaeoJP6z_RDxw&sig2=-pzOgMyZBoRynFlp9W2XcA&bvm=bv.93990622,d.c2E)**. Do this soon before your CPU falls out (mine did).

Comment: I kind of suspected something like this. Btw, what do you mean by "CPU falls out"?

Comment: before It catches fire or crashes

Comment: BTW Welcome to AskUbuntu, Please create an account to start expanding and sharing your knowledge.